# error of sql query in MS Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, windows-7, ms-access-2010

I need to do a sql query in MS Access.

But I got error in MS Access:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM table1
   where not exists 
   (
     SELECT *  
     FROM table2
     where table2.id = table1.id
   ) as t
 )  as t1, table3
 where  table3.id = t1.id
```

Syntax error: (missing operator) in query expression 'not exists ( ... ) as t'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The not exists subselect does not require an alias.  Note that I've removed the `as t`

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM table1
   where not exists 
   (
     SELECT *  
     FROM table2
     where table2.id = table1.id
   ) 
 )  as t1, table3
 where  table3.id = t1.id
```

You might also consider using an `inner join` and a `left join` to get rid of your `not exists`:

This should be exactly equivalent of the above:

```
SELECT t1.*, t3.* 
FROM 
  table1 t1 
  inner join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.id
  left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where
  t2.id is null
```